# Clustered Index Update from within a cursor issue

Tags: sql-server, cursor, clustered-index

I have a clustered index that is over several fields.  One of these fields is CustomerID.  I have a cursor that reads from that table, and then updates the CustomerID.  The problem is that it cause an infinite loop.  I assume that when it changes the customerid field, the clustered index is modified and the table is restructured for the index.  This modification seems to invalidate my cursor so the FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor never reaches the end.

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM AccountSoftwareRegCursor 
INTO @CurrentAccountSoftwareRegUId

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

    UPDATE 
        Licensing.AccountSoftwareRegistration 
    SET 
        AccountUid = @ToAccountUid, 
        CompanyId = @ToCompanyId, 
        UpdatedBy = isnull(@UpdatedBy,'Asset Transfer'),
        UpdatedByAccount = @UpdatedByAccount,
        UpdatedOn = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE 
        AccountSoftwareRegUid = @CurrentAccountSoftwareRegUId
```

Is there any command i can issue to stop the table from updating the table for the clustered index until after the cursor finishes?

Comment: Can you show us the whole code, from the population of your cursor till you close it?; I mean, for all we know, you can be missing some other statement that makes your cursor go on an infinite loop

Comment: There is NO REASON to do this in a cursor. This should be a set based operation. Please read: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: I cannot show you the whole code, i am sorry.  I am not even sure of what my employers policy is on what I have showed already.  I have implemented the accepted answer below as a bandaid.  I am now rewriting the stored proc to not use a cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot rewrite this to eliminate the cursor, you'll want to declare your cursor as STATIC.

```
DECLARE AccountSoftwareRegCursor CURSOR STATIC
FOR
SELECT...
```

From the [DECLARE CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) documentation:

> STATIC
>
> Defines a cursor that makes a
>   temporary copy of the data to be used
>   by the cursor. All requests to the
>   cursor are answered from this
>   temporary table in tempdb; therefore,
>   modifications made to base tables are
>   not reflected in the data returned by
>   fetches made to this cursor, and this
>   cursor does not allow modifications.

Comment: While this does solve the problem technically, I would suggest looking into what Cade suggested below about not including CustomerID in the Clustered Index.  Updating the Clustered Index also cascades to all Non-Clustered Indexes on that table which increases the time it takes for the operation to complete AND the potential for DeadLocks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing this into a set-based operation instead of using a cursor, your clustered index having a column which is changing should be a red flag:

Please review [Microsoft's Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx)

The clustered index should be [unique, narrow, static and ever-increasing](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)